# Jasperserver authenticate against azure active directory (aad)

Tags: java, azure, jasperserver

has anybody managed to authenticate jasperserver (version 6.2.2 - community edition) against the azure active directory?

I have tried with the sample in the link below (adapted the config)
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-oauth-20-tibco-jasperreports-server-v61

Is it possible with spring within jasper?

PS: Beside the I have successfully authenticated a java webapp over oauth2.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your question "Is it possible with spring within jasper". Could you describe in detail? I think it's unnecessary for authenticating again for integrating jasper with your java webapp if you have successfully authenticated over oauth2.

Comment: Hi Peter, just wanted to state, that I have successfully authenticated a java web app against aad, but was unable to do the same with jasperserver.

Comment: ...according to the jasperserver documentation, spring security is part of jasperserver.